# OpenCV compareFaces with EigenFaceRecognizer

Tags: android, opencv, compare, face-detection

I have an application that needs to compare the face in a bitmap, it needs to be compared with another bitmap.
In this case it will be a reference bitmap and another bitmap that was taken at that moment to perform the comparison of the face in the two images.

```
class FaceComparator(private val faceBitmaps: List<Bitmap>)
{
    private val recognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.create()

    init {
        trainRecognizer()
    }

    private fun trainRecognizer()
    {
        try {
            val faces = mutableListOf<Mat>()
            val labels = mutableListOf<Int>()
            var label = 1

            for (faceBitmap in faceBitmaps)
            {
                val face = Mat()
                Utils.bitmapToMat(faceBitmap, face)
                val size = Size(200.0, 200.0)
                Imgproc.resize(face, face, size)
                Imgproc.cvtColor(face, face, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces.add(face)
                labels.add(label)
                label++
            }

            val labelsMat = Mat(labels.size, 1, CvType.CV_32SC1)
            for (i in labels.indices)
                labelsMat.put(i, 0, labels[i].toDouble())

            recognizer.train(faces, labelsMat)
        }
        catch (e: Exception)
        {
            Log.e("Exception on recognizer.train", e.toString())
        }
    }

    fun compareFaces(bitmap1: Bitmap, bitmap2: Bitmap): Double
    {
        //val recognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.create()
        val faceSize = Size(200.0, 200.0)

        //Preprocess first face image
        val face1 = Mat()
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1, face1)
        Imgproc.resize(face1, face1, faceSize)
        Imgproc.cvtColor(face1, face1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        //Preprocess second face image
        val face2 = Mat()
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap2, face2)
        Imgproc.resize(face2, face2, faceSize)
        Imgproc.cvtColor(face2, face2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        //Train recognizer with first face
        //recognizer.train(listOf(face1), Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_32SC1, Scalar(0.0)))

        //Predict label and distance of second face
        val predictions = IntArray(1)
        val distances = DoubleArray(1)
        recognizer.predict(face2, predictions, distances)

        //Return distance between faces
        return distances[0]
    }

    fun compareFaces2(bitmap: Bitmap): Double
    {
        val mat = Mat()
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)
        val size = Size(200.0, 200.0) // tamanho desejado
        Imgproc.resize(mat, mat, size)
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        val predictions = IntArray(1)
        val distances = DoubleArray(1)
        recognizer.predict(mat, predictions, distances)
        val label = predictions[0]
        val distance = distances[0]
        return if (label == -1)
            Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        else
            distance
    }
}
```

I tried to compare the face in the two bitmaps sent but it's not getting a certain return.
In the precise case that in the compareFaces method bitmap1 is the reference image and bitmap2 will be the image used to check if the face in bitmap2 is equal to the face of bitmap1